# How do I add a caption to a diagram generated with qtree?

Tags: diagrams, qtree

I have a diagram that I created with qtree, but would like to add a caption to it. How can this be done?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) how about putting it in a `figure` and using `\caption`?

Comment: This seems to always give Figure 1. <my caption>, and places the diagram in the center of the next page, rather than inline with the text. Is there any alternative to this?

Comment: Should the desired caption have a particular formatting? I mean do you want to number the diagram and have a label for it as in `Diagram 1: tree showing....`?

Comment: Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you want to achieve.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina - yes, exactly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to use the [`newfloat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/newfloat) package to define a new floating object, so then you can use the standard `\caption` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{newfloat}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=lod]{diagram}

\begin{document}

\begin{diagram}
\centering
\Tree [.S This [.VP [.V is ] \qroof{a simple tree}.NP ] ]\par
\caption{the caption for this diagram}
\end{diagram}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The package offers some other customization possibilities and it cooperates with the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package.