# Caption and label tikz-qtree inside figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I want to create a figure caption for my tikz-qtree. Unfortunately it does not compile.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,a4paper,oneside
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{pgfplots}           
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.Anwendungssoftware [.Standardsoftware] [.Individualsoftware [.Extraktionswerkzeug] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Unterteilung in Standard- / Individualsoftware nach \cite{Abts.2011}}
\label{fig:UnterteilungStandardIndividualsoftware}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I took a look at this question: [How do I add a caption to a diagram generated with qtree?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101531/how-do-i-add-a-caption-to-a-diagram-generated-with-qtree)

but when I add newfloat package I get a lot of float errors, possibly because of other packages.

Removing tikzpicture environment also does not work.

Everytime the error message says `Paragraph ended before \@@label was complete`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `tikz-qtree` syntax needs to have (at least) a blank space before the closing `]`. Once you add the spaces, your example works (notice the space before the closing bracket in the lines `Standardsoftware ]` and `Extraktionswerkzeug ]`):

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,a4paper,oneside
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{pgfplots}           
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}    

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree 
[.Anwendungssoftware 
  [.Standardsoftware ] 
  [.Individualsoftware 
    [.Extraktionswerkzeug ] 
  ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Unterteilung in Standard- / Individualsoftware nach \cite{Abts.2011}}
\label{fig:UnterteilungStandardIndividualsoftware}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Some people prefer this (placing the closing `]` in a line of its own) to avoid forgetting to leave the blank space:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree 
[.Anwendungssoftware 
  [.Standardsoftware 
  ] 
  [.Individualsoftware 
    [.Extraktionswerkzeug 
    ] 
  ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'd suggest you not to use just `[h]` for float placement; either use a less restrictuve option or, better yet, not specification at all.

Comment: oh man such a mistake.. thanks. regarding the `[h]`. I am aware that this is a word-thing but to be honest having a figure being in another section or just randomly befor the mention of it, is IMHO annoying for the reader. I know that LaTeX will place it where it is best. The end result have almost never satisfied me. A las maybe I am doing something entirely wrong here?? Please enlighten me if so. :)